# .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack Unable to Uninstall

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, atmelstudio

I'm currently trying to install [Atmel Studio 6.2 with .NET](http://www.atmel.com/tools/atmelstudio.aspx) and the Visual Studio Isolated Shell 10.0 portion of the install is giving me some trouble.

When I attempt to install Atmel Studio, it tries to install .NET Framework 4 and immediately fails with the resulting log:

```
[08/26/14,07:57:20] .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack: [2] Error: Installation failed for component .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack. MSI returned error code 1612
[08/26/14,07:57:21] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack is not installed.
[08/26/14,07:57:21] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated) - ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[08/26/14,07:57:21] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types was not attempted to be installed.
[08/26/14,07:57:21] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects was not attempted to be installed.
[08/26/14,07:57:21] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Help Viewer 1.0 x64 was not attempted to be installed.
[08/26/14,07:57:21] VS70pgui: [2] CFinishPage::UpdateFinal(): Could not find the readme.htm in the client directory as expected!
[08/26/14,08:01:54] .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack: [2] Error: Installation failed for component .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack. MSI returned error code 1612
[08/26/14,08:01:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack is not installed.
[08/26/14,08:01:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated) - ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[08/26/14,08:01:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types was not attempted to be installed.
[08/26/14,08:01:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects was not attempted to be installed.
[08/26/14,08:01:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Help Viewer 1.0 x64 was not attempted to be installed.
[08/26/14,08:01:55] VS70pgui: [2] CFinishPage::UpdateFinal(): Could not find the readme.htm in the client directory as expected!
[08/26/14,08:08:30] .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack: [2] Error: Installation failed for component .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack. MSI returned error code 1612
[08/26/14,08:08:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack is not installed.
[08/26/14,08:08:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated) - ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[08/26/14,08:08:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types was not attempted to be installed.
[08/26/14,08:08:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects was not attempted to be installed.
[08/26/14,08:08:32] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Help Viewer 1.0 x64 was not attempted to be installed.
[08/26/14,08:08:32] VS70pgui: [2] CFinishPage::UpdateFinal(): Could not find the readme.htm in the client directory as expected!
[08/26/14,09:16:38] .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack: [2] Error: Installation failed for component .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack. MSI returned error code 1612
[08/26/14,09:16:38] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack is not installed.
[08/26/14,09:16:38] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated) - ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[08/26/14,09:16:38] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types was not attempted to be installed.
[08/26/14,09:16:38] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects was not attempted to be installed.
[08/26/14,09:16:38] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Help Viewer 1.0 x64 was not attempted to be installed.
[08/26/14,09:16:39] VS70pgui: [2] CFinishPage::UpdateFinal(): Could not find the readme.htm in the client directory as expected!
[08/26/14,12:42:39] .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack: [2] Error: Installation failed for component .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack. MSI returned error code 1612
[08/26/14,12:42:39] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack is not installed.
[08/26/14,12:42:39] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated) - ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[08/26/14,12:42:39] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types was not attempted to be installed.
[08/26/14,12:42:39] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects was not attempted to be installed.
[08/26/14,12:42:39] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Help Viewer 1.0 x64 was not attempted to be installed.
[08/26/14,12:42:39] VS70pgui: [2] CFinishPage::UpdateFinal(): Could not find the readme.htm in the client directory as expected!
```

My first reaction was to try and uninstall/reinstall .NET Framework 4. When I attempt to uninstall it, I receive the following error:

> The path 'C:\Users\MyUser\appdata\local\temp\sit31981.tmp\wcu\mtpack\NetFx_DTP.msi' cannot be found. Verify that you have access to this location and try again, or try to find the installation package 'NetFx_DTP.msi' in a folder from which you can install the product Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack

I've tried searching around my computer to try and find this file with no luck. I've also done some research to try and find the file 'NetFx_DTP.msi' by itself with no luck there either.

If anyone has any tips on how to possibly solve this, it'd be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This Microsoft Support post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/visual-studio-isolated-shell-10-error-code-1612/d55c6b5d-1e91-4f3d-bd9c-ef88057c1e95)   addresses the issues I was running into. [FixIt](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall/) was able to reset the corrupted registry entries and get everything back to normal!

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For Windows 10 / Server 2012R2:

- Download the [Windows 7.1 SDK ISO image](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=8279)
- Unzip it
- Run `Setup\MTPack\netfx_dtp.msi EXTUI=1`

You should now have a `%programfiles(x86)%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\` folder with the 4.0 stuff.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee225240(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: `EXTUI=1` was the most important part. Otherwise it would refuse to install manually.

Comment: Do you know the link for Windows Web Server 2008 R2?